# Super resolution image from low quality Images

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a set of low quality images of the same license plate. In which there is unknown shift, rotation, scale and intensity variation. My aim is to use these image to create `good quality` 
image using super resolution. I have downloaded OpenCV code for `super resolution` which uses images with known shift.
I couldn't find any algorithms which uses images with unknown shift, rotation and intensity variations. Can I create a super resolution  image from these samples, So that new image can be used for OCR after segmentation. Can anybody post link for super resolution code which uses images of unknown shift, rotation, and scale variation. `??`

sample images ::

```
[http://i61.tinypic.com/20utst0.jpg
http://i60.tinypic.com/fz3cw9.jpg
http://i57.tinypic.com/2iszhu8.jpg
http://i58.tinypic.com/bitqap.jpg][1]
```

Comment: So basically, you're trying to recreate CSI pictures :) I think it is nearly impossible to do such a thing.

Comment: i have cropped these license plates from a video in which vehicle is at different positions.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt if you can find the code covering your specific task exactly. But you're task seems reasonable to me. You can follow the following steps

1. Perform image registration (image 1 to all the rest) considering rotation, scale and gray-scale changes. In your'e case you can find special points like plate corners, middle of digits etc, then find the transformation between the two images by means of linear-regression.
2. If the accuracy achieved in stage 1 is not enough, you can refine the registration using an affine-version of the Lucas-Kanade method
3. Warp the images (all towards image 1)
4. Use the super-resolution code you have, with the warped images and no shift as input